# Get full json struct in a belongsTo relation

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to setup a basic model relation in Loopback by creating a `belongsTo` relationship.

I have two models defined like this:

Contract.json

```
{
  "name": "Contract",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mssql": {
    "schema": "dbo",
    "table": "Contract"
  },
  "properties": {
    "contractid": {
       // some property stuff
    },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "employee": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Employee",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Employee.json

```
{
  "name": "Employee",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mssql": {
    "schema": "dbo",
    "table": "Employee"
  },
  "properties": {
    "employeeid": {
       // some property definitions...
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "contracts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Contract",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

When I do a `GET` request on a `Contract` with a specfic `id` I get the result:

Calling: `/api/Contracts/55`

```
{
  "contractid": 55,
  "employeeId": 83
}
```

Which is fine so far. But when I do a `GET` request on `Contract`, also getting the `Employee`s I expect to get an ouput like this:

Calling: `/api/Contracts/55/employee`

```
{
  "contractid": 55,
  "employee": {
      "employeeid": 83
  }
}
```

But instead I'm only getting the `Employee` object without its `Contract`:

```
{
    "employeeid": 83
}
```

Why is that?

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I have the wrong expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `/api/Contracts/55?filter[include]=employee`

or:

```
/api/Contracts/55?filter={"include":"employee"}
```

You can set the Contract model default scope to include employee objects by adding a "scope" section:

```
"scope": {
    "include": "employee"
  }
```

Comment: Cool, that did t he trick! But now I'm wondering, is this how you supposed to do it? So with other words, calling `/api/Contracts/55/employee` is supposed to just return an `employee` object?

Comment: You can make this default behaviour using default scope (added to answer). In many cases though you don't want to return the whole graph due to the additional bandwidth and db calls that may be required.